# Read access when Spring @Transactional in progress

Tags: java-8, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have a spring @Transactional annotation on a method where I'm performing multiple DB operations, which is almost taking 20 secs to complete the transaction.

```
@Transactional
public void performOperations() {

    --DB operations of couple of tables
}
```

When the Transaction in progress, I tried to access the DB with sampel SQL select query from SQL developer GUI.

But spring @Transactional is locking the DB which is restricting to have a read access from SQL developer GUI.

Is there any way to acquire read access when the Transaction in progress?

Comment: @Transaction will not lock the DB/table for read operation. If you are not able to connect to DB from SQL developer, then check if you have stale sessions that was not closed properly before and kill those sessions.

Comment: What database are you using? Some databases lock rows for reading while working on them. Also what operations are you actually doing?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL, And I'm doing the delete and insert operations inside @Transactional